# How to download data from Firebase in Android efficiently?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

After doing some research it is still not clear to me how exactly Android downloads data from Firebase. Android has a lot of best practices for performance such as using an AsyncTask or Volley, but I need to understand how Firebase operates before I can make decisions about them.

To be more specific, does Firebase load data in a separate thread? When I am downloading profiles (a profile picture with some text) in a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter I would like to download the text for each profile first and the pictures in a separate thread. I know how to do this when downloading data from the internet normally but I do not know what Firebase already does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase uses a single separate thread for all its (network, disk, etc) operations. But your callbacks will always be invoked on the main thread, so that you can safely interact with the UI.

But if you perform any non-trivial operations in the callback, it is (as usual) your job to perform those operations off the main thread. So a `AsyncTask` or `IntentService` are still the proper approach there.

Comment: Thank's, that makes a lot of sense. I do not want to make this topic too broad so I ask just one final question.
Firebase stores a local copy of the data, does that mean that it caches automatically or do I still have to do that myself?

Comment: Firebase keeps all data that the app has active listeners to in memory. If you detach the last listener for a location, the data will be removed from memory. If you've enable disk persistence it will also keep a copy of all data the app has recently retrieved on disk.